# Can I go back to a previous version of a CMS page in PrestaShop 1.6.0.9

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm pretty new to PrestaShop...Is there a way to revert back to a previous version of a CMS page? Like, if someone updated the wrong page by mistake and wanted to go back to the previous version quickly? Most other CMS systems have some kind of versioning but I cannot find anything from PrestaShop documentation or Google. Please let me know if more information is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported in PrestaShop.

Comment: So what happens if some product info got overwritten by mistake? I have to restore the whole site from a backup just to get one file back?

Comment: In most of the cases you can use the "Back" browser button, and the UI should be prefilled with the old values. PrestaShop itself does not have "rollback" functionality.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Thanks for the info!